# Why is this block div affecting two floated divs?

Tags: css, css-float, margin

Suppose I have three `<div>`s in my page,:

```
<div id="left" class="test" style="float:left;"></div>
<div id="right" class="test" style="float:right;"></div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

with this css:

```
.test{  background:black;height:200px;width:200px;}
#footer{    background:yellow;margin:20px 0 0 0;}
```

What I want is:

- let the "#left" float to left
- let the "#right" float to right
- change nothing about the "#footer", just set it to `margin: 20px;`

The result is below:

[image]

But I wonder why the floated divs also have the same margin as the `#footer`. They are floated, so they're independent of the other elements, why would the `#footer` could affect them?

Comment: I can't reproduce this (jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xrsPN/). The `left` and `right` don't have the top margins in my test.

Comment: @ZYDN in your test you have not reset the default body padding, so the padding is stopping the footer margin adjoining with the body margin - so no margin collapsing - resets (commonly in use today) will reset both the HTML and body's default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as well as `clear:both` on the footer, just adding a container "wrapper" div around the the elements will stop this happening - [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/txMkU/)

actually adding `clear: both;` on the footer won't give you a 20px gap between the floats and the footer either, you would actually need to add the 20px bottom margin to the floats - the reasons are all linked.. to [**clearance** or non clearance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control) and it's interaction with [**Collapsing Margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

### Why?

You said you wanted to know why this is happening, in your OP scenario it's because of **Collapsing Margins**.

You have no clearance involved in the original example, so yes the floats are removed, So the footer margin is still adjoining, therefore collapsing with, the `body` element, so the `body` element is the one getting the margin, and then because the floats are still actually inside the `body` they get the margin too.

As I mentioned above creating a wrapper `div` to "contain" the  floats stops this happening because the rules of collapsing too. However you choose to contain the floats, either with `overflow:hidden`, or by floating the "wrapper" stops this interaction because ..  from the section on collapsing margins:

> Vertical margins of elements that
>   establish new block formatting
>   contexts (such as floats and elements
>   with 'overflow' other than 'visible')
>   **do not collapse** with their in-flow
>   children.

you see that both of the properties, float and 'overflow other than visible' are the means to "contain floated children" - actually they're establishing a new block formatting context, but in easy speak most know it as "containing floats" ;)

Now once you have that, that fixes your first bit but then if you decide to introduce `clear:both` on the footer, the modern browsers will **not** put a 20px margin between the floats and the footer.. this is actually correct.. from the section on the `clear` property (my bold):

> Then the amount of clearance is set to
>   the greater of:
>
> 1. The amount necessary to place the border edge of the block **even with**
>      the bottom outer edge of the lowest
>      float that is to be cleared.
> 2. The amount necessary to place the top border edge of the block at
>      its hypothetical position.

In order to place the top edge of the footer below the floats (in your example) the browser has to introduce 200px of **clearance**, which is far more than 20px so it follows rule 1. If your top margin on the footer was 220px, the margin would be greater than the any clearance needed, so it would follow rule 2.

So, if you did actually want the footer to be 20px below the floats no matter what their heights are, you would put the 20px as a bottom margin onto the two floats, so it [the footer] would clear, via clearance rule 1, the floats with the required gap/margin, no matter which was float the longest.

PS: Don't test the above in IE7 or below - and I hope it wasn't too boring ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `clear: both` to the `#footer` CSS. That should make the footer render below the floating divs with the margin you want.

Comment: Actually I konw how can I solv my problem,however,my wonder is that why this happend?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and this may solve your problem:

```
<div id="right" class="test" style="float:right;"></div>
<div id="left" class="test"></div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

CSS remaining unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test before finding this page that has two boxes, with the right-floated one being affected by the left block one (which comes after it) here: http://jsfiddle.net/4r75s/

The overflow trick that prevents parent divs collapsing when they only contain floated content seems to work here, that is setting overflow to hidden, auto or scroll. I wrapped them in a containing div to do it and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/4r75s/1/

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```